# Why does the animation gets stuck on Android sometimes?

Tags: android, animation

I have been trying to animate view in android and I have done that animation but that problem is that some times the animation stuck in the middle I don't know why.

what I am doing is I have a view in the middle and that view contains horizontal list view and when an item is clicked the view animates to the top and on the top when user clicks it goes down to its original position

here is the code for animation.

```
public class DropDownAnim extends Animation {
 private final float targetHeight;
 private final View view;
 private final boolean down;


 public DropDownAnim(View view, float targetHeight, boolean down) {
    this.view = view;
    this.targetHeight = targetHeight;
    this.down = down;
}

@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    int newHeight;
    if (down) {
        newHeight = (int) (targetHeight * interpolatedTime);
    } else {
        newHeight = (int) (targetHeight * (1 - interpolatedTime));
    }
    view.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight;
    view.requestLayout();


}

  @Override
  public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth,
                       int parentHeight) {
     super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean willChangeBounds() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

when the view that contains horizontal list view and in that an item is clicked I am doing

```
DropDownAnim drop = new DropDownAnim(_View, (width_And_Height[1] / 100) *
                   Utils.get_Percentage_For_animate_View_Based_On_Mobile_Resloution(),
                true); //true means go to top
        drop.setDuration(DURATION);
        _View.setAnimation(drop);
        _View.startAnimation(drop);
```

and when the view is on the top

```
 DropDownAnim drop = new DropDownAnim(_View, (width_And_Height[1] / 100) * Utils.get_Percentage_For_animate_View_Based_On_Mobile_Resloution(),
                    false);//false means go to is orignal position
            drop.setDuration(DURATION);
            _View.setAnimation(drop);
            _View.startAnimation(drop);
```

this is returning the height of the screen.

```
width_And_Height[1]
```

first when the horizontal scroll view is in the center and i click on mad it goes up and when the horizontal scroll view is on top and i click on map it comes to its orignal position.

But now the problem is some times the view not come to its orignal position from top and stuck in the middle

here are the images.

**when the horizontal scroll view is in the middle of screen**

[image]

**when the horizontal scroll view is on The Top of screen**

[image]

**when the view not come to its original position from top and stuck in the middle**

[image]

I dont know what is the problem

Thank's for making time for my question,and please **HELP :)**

Comment: When you down Vote a question or answer, kindly give reason....

Comment: please remove view.requestLayout() from applyTransformation and write it only once after starting animation

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are extending an Animation. If you are trying to change the position or height of a view you should be using PropertyAnimations.

If you are trying to grow a view use a simple `ObjectAnimator` and do the following.

```
ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mView,"scaleX",0,2);
animation.setDuration(duration);
animation.start();
```

Comment: sory for late rep i dont want to move the view but to move upward and also expand the view

Comment: Move what upward. And what do you mean when you say expand the view. Despite both of those extending Animation is not right if you are trying to animate a property of a view. This is why I suggest you use ObjecrAnimators.